# Architectural level is mvc in smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk

1.mvc is architecture ui-component?

```
ToggleComponent
   ToggleModel
   ToggleView
   ToggleControlle
```

2.Or mvc is a component architecture?

```
App
   AppModel
   AppView
      ToggleButtonComponent
      SelectComponent
      MenuComponent
         ButtonComponent
         ButtonComponent
   AppController
```

Question strictly in the context of smalltalk.

Comment: What level _of what_ is "reserved MVC"? (And what does "reserved MVC" mean?) If this an architecture question, why should it be dependent on Smalltalk? Sorry, I'm really not sure what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

I think (or better said, I learned) that MVC (acronym for Model-View-Controller) is a framework. A way to define some collaborating roles among parts at a high level of abstraction. That would be more similar to your second option, but I´m not sure if this answers your question